# Can I access ScriptArgs from a Script Pack?

Tags: scriptcs

For ScriptCs scripts I'd like to write a Script Pack that is using command line arguments.

scriptcs myscript.csx -- some args

Within a script I use ScriptArgs, but is it also available somehow from within a Script Pack?

Comment: It could be if you express your need [here](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/pull/420) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `IScriptPackSession` interface which is passed to your script pack on initialization now has a property called `ScriptArgs` :) See the [source](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/pull/420).

Answer (score 1):

Not with the current design.

With that said, that's a good idea - I suggest you file an issue on github - https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs